# why do i get these results using rstrip()?

Tags: python, string

I want to keep the file names without the.csv extension, but using rstrip('.csv') deletes the last letter in the strings ending in s:

```
data_files = [
    "ap_2010.csv",
    "class_size.csv",
    "demographics.csv",
    "graduation.csv",
    "hs_directory.csv",
    "sat_results.csv"
]

data_names = [name.rstrip('.csv') for name in data_files]
```

I get this results:

```
["ap_2010", "class_size", "demographic","graduation","hs_directory", "sat_result"]
```

The end s of strings demographics and sat_results has been removed, why does this happen??

Comment: From the docs for `rstrip()`: *"Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string; the characters in the string will be stripped from the end of the string this method is called on."*

Comment: `.rstrip('.csv')` means to remove as many of the four characters `.`, `c`, `s`, and `v` as possible from the end of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `rstrip()` strips all characters separately from the end of your string.

```
>>> 'abcdxyx'.rstrip('yx')
'abcd'
```

This will search for `y` and `x` to strip from the right side of your string. If you like to remove the `.csv` you can use split instead.

```
>>> "ap_2010.csv".split('.')[0]
"ap_2010"
```

Also for Filenames it is good practice to use the function `os.path.splitext`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.splitext('ap_2010.csv')[0]
"ap_2010"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get your intended output with this:

```
data_files = [
    "ap_2010.csv",
    "class_size.csv",
    "demographics.csv",
    "graduation.csv",
    "hs_directory.csv",
    "sat_results.csv"
]

data_names = [name.replace('.csv','') for name in data_files]
```

Comment: What if one of the files is named `"some.csv.something.csv.csv"`?

Comment: In that case, all of the `.csv` would be removed, but I'm not totally convinced that is relevant to what the OP is asking here :)